# Python split unicode characters and words

Tags: python

I'm running a data science project and i need your help.

My string is:

```
string = 'Test'
```

and I expect that output:

```
s1 = ''

s2 = 'Test'
```

Comment: Based on the logic behind your expected output there might be a lot of ways to do that. Have you tried anything yet, so that we can guess what's that logic?

Comment: Please ask a question and demonstrate some effort. StackOverflow is not a code writing service.

Comment: Sorry guys, Thx for help it works great

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll assume that your string is always of the form `"<emoticon><alphabets>"`. I'll then splice the string.

```
# Count number of alphabets first
num = [c.isalpha() for c in string].count(True)
# Splice string based on the result
s1 = string[:-num]
s2 = string[-num:]
```

Comment: Did you test this at all?

Comment: I've removed my vote because your answer is not *wrong*... However I'm sure you can see how this "solution" has many problems. You're hardcoding values where you can't be sure that they will always be the same.

Comment: Agreed, I hope this answer is better

Comment: Awesome - the main thing I was missing was declaring that you are making an assumption - since the OP has not clearly defined his issue - the only thing we *can* do is make assumptions - it's important to disclose that :)

Comment: I'll keep that in mind for the unclear questions, thank you @Lix :)