# Python 3.5 separate words from unicode symbols

Tags: python, regex

I am working with text processing and I have an array with unicode characters and words. I want to split them so I can process the data into a machine learning algorithm.

For example:

This is my array:

```
arr = ['mpla mpalampla', 'mpala' , 'mpalampala', '']
```

and I want this:

```
resultarr = ['mpla', 'mpala', '', 'mpla', 'mpala', '', '', 'mpalampala', '','']
```

I know it is a complex question, please feel free to ask for details.

Comment: Use `[x for item in arr for x in re.findall(r"\s+|([a-zA-Z]+|\S)", item) if x]`

Comment: Dude it works thx

Comment: Yes, for the string above. However, not knowing what you are doing I cannot post an answer since this might break later with another kind of input. Please update it with the specifications for this task and what you tried to solve it. Else, the question should be closed as unclear.

Comment: Is this homework? someone else asked a very similar question yesterday: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41286066/python-split-unicode-characters-and-words

Comment: Nop it is not a homework. but thx for the post its really usefull....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily do it using regular expressions:

```
import re

arr = ['mpla mpalampla', 'mpala' , 'mpalampala', '']

temp_str = " ".join(arr)

resultarr = re.split(r'([^a-z]|\s)', temp_str)

resultarr = list(filter(
    lambda item: item not in ('', ' '),
    resultarr
))

print(resultarr) # ['mpla', 'mpala', '', 'mpla', 'mpala', '', '', 'mpalampala', '','']
```